# regex see if lowercase exists

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm still learning with regex.

I'm trying to check if the string contains ANY lowercase values. If it does, I just want to return false.

I've read answers on here, but they don't seem to work in my program, YET, they work in a regex emulator online.

```
if (str.matches("[a-z]+"){
System.out.println("removed");
return false;
```

This seems to highlight the lowercase letters in regexr but not in my program. Any help please?

Comment: .matches will check if the entire string matches the regex, not if the regex matches some substring. You probably want `.*[a-z].*` In java you could also do `!str.toUpperCase().equals(str)`.

Comment: One of the answers to the LAST question you asked explains why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for the correct regular expression itself `.*[a-z].*` as provided by @Adrian Leonhard as a comment above, is indeed correct. However, I think its important to mention that regular expressions take a very long time to compile, and if this if statement is nested in a loop it might be a good idea to use the full regular expression implementation in `java.util.regex.*`. rather than the convenience methods provided in String. To do so, first compile a `Pattern` object from your string.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[a-z].*");
```

This way the regex only has to be compiled once instead of every time `String#matches(String regex)` is called. Regex compilation is very [computationally intensive](http://chrononsystems.com/blog/hidden-evils-of-javas-stringsplit-and-stringr). Then, create a matcher using your input string.

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

Now, call `Matcher#find()`

```
if(m.find()) {
//Your code here
}
```

However, you could also just test to see if

```
str.toUpperCase().equals(str)
```

It's up to you. I would only use regex if absolutely necessary as it can slow down your program, and isn't very elegant in this case. At least you know how to use them properly in the future now.